# Office 2010 Save Dialog not showing on computer through remote desktop

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2010

I am using remote deskop to remote into a server, and run a C# .Net application that saves information to Excel.

I am opening a saveas dialog on a server using Excel's built-in interop diaglog:

```
dialog = dialogs[InteropExcel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs];
dialog.Show(filename);
```

The Dialog does not show, and it just pauses there, as if waiting for the dialog to be closed. I tested it on other computers using Office 2003, 2007 and 2010, but none of them have any issues.

The server uses Server 2007 SP2.

Comment: What happens if you hit 'escape' when the pause happens?

Comment: If hitting 'escape' works then it sounds to me like the dialog is being shown "off screen" somewhere.  Can you force it to a particular location?

Comment: I press Alt, Left, Down, move. No matter where I move it to, it is not visable. I think it is a problem with Excel dialog.

Comment: Folks, this seems a little far into the realm of programming to go to a sister site. Let's leave this here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with an add-on in Excel. It causes the the "Open" and "Save As" dialog to crash when you open it. I found the solution on this page:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vsto/thread/83382a34-5087-40cf-b12a-1121303627c0